# TCPDF document break

Tags: php, printing, tcpdf

I have a script which creates a report as a pdf containing multiple pages through TCPDF. This works fine. What I want to do is creating a pdf containing multiple reports. This works fine to a point that I have one large pdf containing all pages of all reports.

My problem reveals when printing the pdf on double sided paper. If a report contains uneven number of pages the following report will start on the backside of the last page of the previous report.

Is there a way of telling TCPDF to start a new document within the document so printing on both sides will work correctly?

My code (php):

```
$this->pdf = new TCPDF();
// Loop through all reports
foreach($report as $report):
    // Add pages to the report
    foreach($reportPages as $page):
        $this->pdf->AddPage();
    endforeach;
    // Here I would like to tell to start a new document
    $this->pdf->addDocument(); // I can not find anything in the docs
endforeach;
// Ouput the pdf
$this->pdf->Output('report.pdf');
```

Thankful for any help out there!

Comment: detect if you're on an odd/even page, and add a blank page as necessary.

Comment: Hi Marc! I was thinking about something like that and could solve my problem temporarly. But there should be a more elegant way. If you download multiple reports and merge them, in "preview" in OSX, printing works fine. So that is where my question started.

Comment: that'd depend on whatever you're using to do the merge, then. as far as TC's concerned, it's creating one single PDF, and ensuring even/odd alignment would be up to you.